# Yootheme Widgetkit and Fatica Locator jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, joomla

Let me start by saying that I am a jquery n00b. :(

I have this issue on my website and so far no solution. I have a Joomla website, a Yootheme template and a Fatica Locator component.

I bought both, but there seems to be a jquery conflict (thats what both support teams said), but I don't have a clue... So I went looking for a jquery forum, with people with more knowledge about this then myself.

This is the page I am talking about: http://www.ellenvandrunen.com/santos/dealers

The first time it will probably load perfectly, but the second time the locator map stays empty.

So I consulted Fatica Locator and this is their response:

> This looks like a jQuery conflict/timing issue of some kind. For some
>   reason, the page load trigger is not firing after cache has been
>
> established, so it works the first time, but when the page loads
>   faster, initialize is not called, or is called before the page
>   elements exist.
>
> Something called "Widgetkit" is throwing errors, possibly stopping
>   page executing, meaning our startup code may never get the chance to
>   run after that plugin or library errors out.

So after that I consulted Yootheme (Widgetkit owner) and this is their response:

> That extension is loading another instance of the jQuery library,
>   resulting in a conflict,
>
> http://www.ellenvandrunen.com/santos/components/com_locator/assets/jquery.min.js
>   Have a look at its settings. Does it have an option to disable that
>   loading ?

In the locator component I found an option to turn off  'use jQuery for front-end Ajax yes/no'
I switched to no, but no improvement...

At this moment it stays quiet and I really want to resolve this.

I don't know which information you need to help resolving this, so please let me know. I hope there is a solution...

Within locator I found this:

```
$doc->addScript( JURI::base() . 'components/com_locator/assets/jquery.min.js' );
         $doc->addScript(  JURI::base() . 'components/com_locator/assets/jquery.noconflict.js' );
```

Maybe that could help...

A system check gives this information:

Multiple jQuery Libraries found. Please make sure these don't conflict each other.

```
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery-1.5.2.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery-1.5.2.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.ajaxfileupload.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.ajaxfileupload.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.autogrow.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.autogrow.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.cluetip.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.cluetip.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.colorinput.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.colorinput.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.excanvas.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.excanvas.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.flot.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.flot.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.flydom.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.flydom.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.form.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.form.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.jeditable.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.jeditable.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.jmap.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.jmap.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.maskedinput.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.maskedinput.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.metadata.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.metadata.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.rating.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.rating.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.slimbox2.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.slimbox2.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.ui-all.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.ui-all.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.validate.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.validate.min.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.wysiwyg.js
/components/com_comprofiler/js/jquery-1.5.2/jquery.wysiwyg.min.js
/components/com_jce/editor/libraries/jquery/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js
/components/com_jce/editor/libraries/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js
/components/com_jce/editor/libraries/jquery/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js
/components/com_locator/assets/jquery.min.js
/components/com_locator/assets/jquery.noconflict.js
```

Edit:

Thanks Lodder for taking the effort:

I changed this in view.html.php where I believe the jquery is called.

```
/* $doc->addScript( JURI::base() . 'components/com_locator/assets/jquery.min.js' ); */
         /* $doc->addScript(  JURI::base() . 'components/com_locator/assets/jquery.noconflict.js' );*/

         if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $doc->addScript( JURI::root() . 'components/com_locator/assets/jquery.min.js' );
}
```

But I don't think it worked... This is way over my head I'm afraid! I'm getting a bit desperate here...

Comment: A system check gives this information:

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the fact 2 jQuery libraries are being imported.

In the Fatica Locator component, where they are importing jQuery, replace it with the following code:

```
if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $doc->addScript( JURI::root() . 'components/com_locator/assets/jquery.min.js' );
}
```

This basically checks to see if jQuery is being imported already. If not, it imports it.

Hope this helps

On a side note, even though the Yootheme Warp scripts are detecting all those jquery files, it doesn't always matter as all the script does is detect file that have the name *jquery* in them such as *jquery.rating.min.js*

Comment: I'm sorry, I am trying to answer you, but I can't seem to do that right either! Grrr... I added the answer to my original post, maybe that helps.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to you site?

Comment: this is the page: http://www.ellenvandrunen.com/santos/dealers

If you need anything else, please let me know.

Comment: I can give you more info, just send me an email to: info [a] fietsjunks.nl

Comment: Ok I had a look at your site. jQuery is being loaded after some Javascript from the component so you are getting an error in the console. Try installing this plugin which should help with the importing of jQuery: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327

Comment: Thanks! I will try that! I'll let you know if it worked! Thanks for helping me! It's bedtime in The Netherlands now, so first thing tomorrow. ; Good night, greetings, Ellen

Comment: Hi Lodder, last night Fatica consulting contacted me and they send me some new files. After installing, the conflict disappeared and now it's working fine! I don't know what changed, but I am very happy it worked! So unfortunately I cannot help future users with the solution, but I'm so happy it's resolved. Thanks again for your help! Ellen